# How to add year and month under Custom Post Type Archive (site.com/post_type/2013/07)?

Tags: wordpress

I register a new Custom Post Type in my Wordpress. Everything works. Now, I am trying to have a side bar archive navigation (something like the normal archive widget which doesn't work for CTPs - at least not for me).

Let's say the name of my Custom Post Type is `boo`, so i can access my archive with: `mysite.com/boo/`. However, I need to access something like `mysite.com/boo/2013/06`.

I also tried to do this with categories without success. Any idea would be very welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom post type yearly/ monthly archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486792/custom-post-type-yearly-monthly-archive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in past with help of plugin, Look at the screenshot first, You will get exact idea how to implement it :)

[Custom Post Type Permlinks](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/screenshots/)

Comment: thanks but I resist to use plugins. It worked though and it might be the simple solution for most of the people.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike plugins very much special for this kind of tasks. I found my answer in this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486792/custom-post-type-yearly-monthly-archive/14841924#14841924). It also creates a function called `get_cpt_archives` that can be used in the side bar instead of a widget.