# How to generate custom post types year archive rewrite rules?

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

Ok, after trying to do it by myself as I usually do with rewrites (but this time for some reason, with no luck) I've found this answer:

[Custom post type yearly/ monthly archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486792/custom-post-type-yearly-monthly-archive/14841924#14841924)

But still doesn't work for me.
If I log the rules, I can find the right one, it gets correctly written:

`["it/press-release/([0-9]{4})/?$"]=>
  string(50) "index.php?post_type=press_article&year=$matches[1]"`

Just for completeness, the FIRST lines loggin the rules are (see the last one below, it's right):

```
array(309) {
  ["it/press-release/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$"]=>
  string(87) "index.php?post_type=press_article&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]"
  ["it/press-release/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"]=>
  string(104) "index.php?post_type=press_article&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&feed=$matches[4]"
  ["it/press-release/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"]=>
  string(104) "index.php?post_type=press_article&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&feed=$matches[4]"
  ["it/press-release/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$"]=>
  string(105) "index.php?post_type=press_article&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]"
  ["it/press-release/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$"]=>
  string(71) "index.php?post_type=press_article&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]"
  ["it/press-release/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"]=>
  string(88) "index.php?post_type=press_article&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]"
  ["it/press-release/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"]=>
  string(88) "index.php?post_type=press_article&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]"
  ["it/press-release/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$"]=>
  string(89) "index.php?post_type=press_article&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]"
  ["it/press-release/([0-9]{4})/?$"]=>
  string(50) "index.php?post_type=press_article&year=$matches[1]"
```

But still it doesn't work. If I try to navigate to `it/press-release/2016` (yes there are posts with that date) I'll get redirected to the front page.

I must say a couple of things:

- I use polylang
- My custom post type is registered like this:

  ```
  $args = array(
     'public' => true,
     'supports' => array('title','editor','page-attributes'),
     'description' => 'Rassegna stampa',
     'labels' => $labels, // omitting here since not relevant
     'rewrite' => array('slug' => pll__('rassegna-stampa')),
     'has_archive' => true,
     'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-media-document'
  );//end args

  register_post_type('press_article',$args);
  ```

Can someone spot the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that in my recent WorPress project where the client wanted to have year based navigation for news (posts in the category News). I used custom rewrite rules to do that.

**Register custom rewrite rule**

```
function px_generate_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite)
{
    $new_rules = array(
        '([^/]+)/archive/(\d+)/?$' => 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&px_archive_year=$matches[2]'
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'px_generate_rewrite_rules');
```

**Register custom query var(s)**

```
function px_query_vars($qvars)
{
    $qvars[] = 'px_archive_year';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'px_query_vars');
```

**Add your custom query**

```
function px_pre_posts($query) 
{

    if( ! is_admin() )
    {
        if( $query->is_main_query() && is_category() )
        {
            set_query_var('date_query', array(
                array(
                    array(
                        'year'  => get_query_var('px_archive_year', date('Y')),
                    )
                )
            ));
            return;
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'px_pre_posts');
```

Please remember that you have to flush rewrite rules if you change something. Remove this code when you're done.

```
add_action('init', function() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
});
```

**NB!** Please pay attention to the title of the page. Every page should have an unique title.

Comment: Yes but my main problem here is wordpress not redirecting to the right template.

Comment: You can use the "template_include" hook to determine the template to use. (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include)

Comment: Yes I already tried, but strangely enough, redirections are done before the hook is executed. Or, in other words, there are a few redirections happening (> site_url > front_page with language) and of course the hook is executed only on the last one (home/lang, not press_article). So, wrong url/redirection, right behaviour since it's on the last redirect that the template has to be determined. So my real problem is with wrong redirection then, not templates, sorry. Something that happens before the template, and thus drives also to the wrong template.